# Php, $result = mysql_query($query) or die ... how can i quickly email a fault?

Tags: php

I would like to add a simple, email me if theres a fault in the query feature.

After

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die
```

What would I add ?

Comment: put the mail() in to die(mail($to,....,....))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a function say

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or reportErrorData()

function reportErrorData()
{
  $fp=popen("/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -oi","w");
  fwrite($fp,"To: DEV_EMAIL\n");
  fwrite($fp,"From: support@support.com\n");
  fwrite($fp,"Subject: System Error\n\n");

  fwrite($fp, "Message: error message\n\n")

  pclose($fp);
}
```

you can also pass in parameters to the reportErrorData function such as the **sql**, **_*FILE*_**, **_*FUNCTION*_** etc.. also it will be handy to email any **$_SESSION, $_GET or $_POST data**, to see who the logged in user was if thats the case and to see where the error occoured i.e which file, function line etc.

hope this helps.

Comment: Cool, I would need to pass in SQL, would I gain the error details in the email ?

Comment: Jules are you THAT helpless? Everything you add to the message body, would be sent to you. Anything you don't add to the message body, wou't jump to it automatically. Surprise, eh?

Comment: the question is not about how complicated it is its about wanting a solution to email the mysql error across with as much information that would make things easier to track the error, also when you have the query emailed it is a lot easier to go through it and find any syntax errors, the $_POST data is sent through so that when the $_POST['something '] is missing we'll know exactely where the problem is.....the down voting is not fair, and you can't down vote someone for giving a sensible answer from their own experience....

Comment: not really worried about the down vote, its just that little appreciation or positive comments i am looking for, to share ideas and make things work better for us. it is frustrating when ppl down vote for no reason...don't you feel?

Comment: @bharath, I didn't down vote you, thought you answer was the start of a solution for me.

Comment: @bharath - why directly using sendmail? simple php mail function does not work?

Comment: @Jules,  thanks i hope my answer gives you enough information to create a nice mysql error feedback function, that'll help you track errors quickly, i've been using such a function for a while and its very handy....

Comment: @Jules there is a mail() function. Just a single function instead of this unportable bloated ugly code. But I see the reason. No one provided an example for it. So, you are as helpless as a sucker. No example! What a trouble

Comment: @bharath what do you do to stop your email box getting flooded ?

Comment: @ajreal, mail() will certainly work. It's just the way i do to quickly email any mysql errors from within my DAO.

Comment: BUMP, think you missed this... @bharath what do you do to stop your email box getting flooded ?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a faulty SQL on frequent access page
or in the event of mysql server down,
is going to flood your inbox.

How about using `error_log` to log the faulty sql into local disk?
log rotate should be cater too (like log file can be `Ymdh.log`

**Not really ASAP notification**

1. setup a cronjob run every minute
2. do a line-count on log file
3. email new lines since last minute
4. if there is no new line, don't email
5. store the line-count into a separate file for next execution

So, you will receive an email to indicate whether any new faulty SQL happen last minute, and no alert if nothing went wrong.

**Since not able to convince you...**

Then you can compare the faulty sql with the error log
If the faulty sql not found in the error log, append into error log, email the faulty sql

You would need to seek for a fashionable way to do string comparison fast in the error log (if the error log is growing too fast)

log rotate can be applied too

Comment: But I'd want to get the error ASAP, but I agree it could flood my inbox, hmmm

Comment: Hmmm, this could get complicated. say I'm out of the office. I could still get flooded with emails...

Comment: a flag file can be made, to see if an email were sent recently. No need to send whole log contents - it's enough just to notify a developer who will be able to check logs online then

Comment: @Jules - you can stop the crontab before out of office

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, I would like to see the error in an email. I really wanted something simple, having flags and reading files seems a bit excessive, but I guess you'd say I'm just lazy ;)

Comment: @Jules I am talking not to you but to answer's author and possible future reader.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$result = mysql_query($query){
    mail(...);
    die;
}
```